# How to avoid losing data when using "outer" in pandas merging?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm working with two dataframes in pandas that look like those bellow (the ones i'm using have more columns, though):

```
>>> df_download
    date        |  app_name           | downloads | app_id
__________________________________________________________
0   2021-01-01  |  music app          | 500       | 100
1   2021-01-01  |  food delivery app  | 900       | 110
2   2021-01-01  |  fitness app        | 1200      | 120
3   2021-01-02  |  music app          | 700       | 100
4   2021-01-02  |  food delivery app  | 750       | 110
5   2021-01-02  |  fitness app        | 3000      | 120
6   2021-01-03  |  music app          | 800       | 100
7   2021-01-03  |  food delivery app  | 100       | 110
8   2021-01-03  |  fitness app        | 400       | 120
```

```
>>> df_active_users
    date        |  app_name           | active_users  | app_id
_______________________________________________________________
0   2021-01-01  |  music app          | 0             | 100
1   2021-01-01  |  food delivery app  | 30000         | 110
2   2021-01-01  |  fitness app        | 90000         | 120
3   2021-01-02  |  music app          | 15000         | 100
4   2021-01-02  |  food delivery app  | 0             | 110
5   2021-01-02  |  fitness app        | 80000         | 120
6   2021-01-03  |  music app          | 20000         | 100
7   2021-01-03  |  food delivery app  | 50000         | 110 
8   2021-01-03  |  fitness app        | 40000         | 120
```

My goal is to merge them. I managed to do that, but somehow, i lost an app. The food delivery app suddently disappear. I used this code:

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df_active_users[['date', 'active_users', 'app_id', 'app_name']],
 df_downloads[['date', 'downloads', 'app_id']], on=['date', 'app_id', 'app_name'], how='outer')
```

Result:

```
df_merged['app_name'].unique()

 array(['music app','fitness app'], dtype=object)
```

Does anyone know how can I get all the data from the two dataframes without losing any app data?
Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: The columns used in your `merge` function do not match with your input sample. Is `app_id` and `app_add` are `product_id`?

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I thought about one thing and wrote another totally different. Now all the columns are `app_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lost anything, your `merge` function (almost) works:

```
out = pd.merge(df_active_users, df_downloads,
               on=['date', 'app_id', 'app_name'],
               how='outer')
```

```
>>> out
        date           app_name  active_users  app_id  downloads
0 2021-01-01          music app             0     100        500
1 2021-01-01  food delivery app         30000     110        900
2 2021-01-01        fitness app         90000     120       1200
3 2021-01-02          music app         15000     100        700
4 2021-01-02  food delivery app             0     110        750
5 2021-01-02        fitness app         80000     120       3000
6 2021-01-03          music app         20000     100        800
7 2021-01-03  food delivery app         50000     110        100
8 2021-01-03        fitness app         40000     120        400

>>> out['app_name'].unique()
array(['music app', 'food delivery app', 'fitness app'], dtype=object)

>>> out['app_name'].value_counts()
music app            3
food delivery app    3
fitness app          3
Name: app_name, dtype: int64
```